# In the conformal mapping, can I choose the exactly same points corresponding to the domain?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

D = {$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1  $} and $\Omega$ = {$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-\sqrt3i| < 2$} $\cap $ {$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z+\sqrt3i| < 2$}.
I want to get the explicit solution of this conformal mapping from D to $\Omega$.

This is how I started:

To solve it I used the bilinear transformation $w = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$.

The points of z I selected were 1, -1, and i (since it is the unit circle).
Then from $\Omega$, I must select other three points.

Here is my question: is it okay to choose 1, -1, i from  $\Omega$ too?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Such a bilinear (or Möbius) transformation will always map circles (such as $\partial D$) to circles (or lines), but the boundary $\partial \Omega$ of $\Omega$ is lens-shaped, with two $60^\circ$ vertices at $-1$ and $1$. So you do need *something* more.

I would start at $\Omega$, use a bilinear map to transport one of the vertices (e.g., $-1$) to infinity ($z\mapsto \frac1{z+1}$); this turns the two circular arcs of $\partial \Omega$ into lines intersecting at still the same angle of $60^\circ$ at the image point of the other vertex $1$, i.e., at $\frac12$. Now transport this to the origin ($z\mapsto z-\frac12$) and raise to a suitable power to turn the 60° into "smooth" 180° ($z\mapsto {z^3}$). In total, this turns $\Omega$ into a half plane, from where you probably know how to arrive at the unit disk.

In total, thus gives you $\Omega \to D$. To obtain $D\to \Omega$, try to invert the function.